# Multiple Handlers in AZURE App Service web.config

Tags: angular, azure, asp.net-core, web-config, angular-universal

Is it possible to have multiple in handlers in the web.config of an Azure App Service?

I have a .Net Core API and a Angular Universal (Node.js) SPA front end. I want to keep these on the same App Service if possible. To do this I think I need to work my web.config file. Is it possible to have all /api requests go to the .Net Core API and the requests to the front end be handled by Node / Angular Universal?

This is what I have for the .Net Core API right now in one App Service:

```
<handlers>
<add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
```

This is what I have in my Angular Universal Node.js front end in another App Service:

```
<handlers>
<add name="iisnode" path="server/main.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
</handlers>
<rewrite>
      <rules>
          <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="^main.js\/debug[\/]?" />
          </rule>
          <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url=".*" />
              <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
          </rule>
      </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I want to combine these two so all API requests (/api) get routed to the .Net Core API and all front end requests (/) go to the Node handler and with the rewrite to use Index.html.

Can anyone help me figure this out if it is possible?